# Adding a Nextcloud account in Unity desktop

Tags: unity, online-accounts, nextcloud

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with Unity desktop and I have the following issue:

There is an option to connect a Nextcloud account as an Online Account.
[image: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Unity - Online Accounts]

I enter the needed server name, username and password; but there’s no “Next” button - nothing I can press to move on.

[image: Nextcloud Account]

I figure this must be either a Ubuntu or Unity issue. (either way, Unity is a part of Ubuntu, provided via the package [`ubuntu-unity-desktop`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/ubuntu-unity-desktop))

Is there a workaround to this issue?

Comment: I think you are correct, and it is probably a Unity issue. You should open a bug report. My guess is that the dialog requires header-bar (Client Side Decoration) buttons, but Unity doesn't show the header-bar buttons. As a matter of fact, on Ubuntu 20.04 (Gnome Shell), I do have the Cancel button at the top left and the Connect button at the top right of this dialog.

Comment: @PJSingh Per your suggestion, I [filed a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1898422).